# Is there a performance disadvantage if an in-line function calls a scalar function?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I've been getting to grips with APPLY, and at the same time reading about the performance improvement of in-line functions over scalar functions ([see Rob Farley's post here](http://blogs.lobsterpot.com.au/2011/11/08/when-is-a-sql-function-not-a-function/)).

I have an application that manages Requests. One Request might apply to a single Person on the system, or to many Persons. Transactions (not SQL TRAN!!) are created against Requests.

So, I've written a little function that returns the latest Transaction of a certain type, given the PersonID and RequestID

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fnReturnPersonCollectionTime] 
(   
    -- Add the parameters for the function here
    @PersonID int, 
    @RequestID int
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(

    SELECT
        TOP 1 Transactions.DateCreated AS TransactionDateTime,
        Transactions.FKPersonID,
        Transactions.FKRequestID
    FROM
        Transactions
    WHERE
        ((Transactions.FKPersonID = @PersonID) AND
        (Transactions.FKRequestID = @RequestID) AND
        (Transactions.FKTransxTypeID = 169))
    ORDER BY
        Transactions.DateTime DESC
)
```

Here it is in action.

```
SELECT 
    Tx.TransactionDateTime
FROM 
    Request INNER JOIN 
    RequestPersons ON Request.ID = RequestPersons.FKRequestID INNER JOIN 
    Person ON RequestPersons.FKPersonID = Person.ID 
    CROSS APPLY dbo.fnReturnPersonCollectionTime(RequestPersons.FKPersonID, RequestPersons.FKRequestID) Tx
```

However.  My colleagues and I don't like the Magic Number 169 in the WHERE clause of the function - in other places in the application we have used scalar functions that return singleton values like these (this is, I believe, generally regarded as a Good Thing, since all such references are centralised to a single location).  This is what it would look like with a call to a scalar function.

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fnReturnPersonCollectionTime] 
(   
    -- Add the parameters for the function here
    @PersonID int, 
    @RequestID int
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(

    SELECT
        TOP 1 Transactions.DateCreated AS TransactionDateTime,
        Transactions.FKPersonID,
        Transactions.FKRequestID
    FROM
        Transactions
    WHERE
        ((Transactions.FKPersonID = @PersonID) AND
        (Transactions.FKRequestID = @RequestID) AND
        (Transactions.FKTransxTypeID = dbo.fnReturnCollectionTransactionID()))
    ORDER BY
        Transactions.DateTime DESC
)
```

So my question is - if my in-line function requires a call to a scalar function, does this negate any good that accrues from writing an in-line function in the first place?

Many thanks

Edward

Comment: I wouldn't say it negates any performance benefit but it isn't likely to help much either. Can you turn the nested scalar function into another inline table valued function?

Comment: I expect I could, and I probably should (not to mention adopting the parameter table design suggested by Hogan below)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would definitely recommend changing up to either an inline table function or a params table (as suggested by Hogan).

I wrote the following test to demonstrate the severe performance difference between the ITVF and the scalar function:

```
;WITH
  L0 AS (SELECT 0 AS c UNION ALL SELECT 0),
  L1 AS (SELECT 0 AS c FROM L0 AS A CROSS JOIN L0 AS B),
  L2 AS (SELECT 0 AS c FROM L1 AS A CROSS JOIN L1 AS B),
  L3 AS (SELECT 0 AS c FROM L2 AS A CROSS JOIN L2 AS B),
  L4 AS (SELECT 0 AS c FROM L3 AS A CROSS JOIN L3 AS B),
  L5 AS (SELECT 0 AS c FROM L4 AS A CROSS JOIN L4 AS B),
  Nums AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) AS n FROM L5)
SELECT n AS KeyField INTO #TestData FROM Nums WHERE n <= 10000;


CREATE TABLE TempData (KeyField INT)
INSERT INTO TempData (KeyField) VALUES (30)
GO

CREATE FUNCTION fn_Test() 
RETURNS INT WITH SCHEMABINDING AS BEGIN
    RETURN (SELECT TOP 1 KeyField FROM dbo.TempData)
END
GO

CREATE FUNCTION fn_Test2 (@KeyField INT)
RETURNS TABLE
RETURN (
    SELECT TOP 1 KeyField FROM dbo.TempData WHERE KeyField = @KeyField
)
GO

SELECT * FROM #TestData WHERE KeyField = dbo.fn_Test()
--SELECT * FROM #TestData td CROSS APPLY dbo.fn_Test2(td.KeyField)

DROP TABLE #TestData
DROP FUNCTION dbo.fn_Test
DROP FUNCTION dbo.fn_Test2
DROP TABLE TempData
```

This populates 10000 rows and uses a function to determine which rows match the TempData (30).  On my system, the scalar function takes ~3 seconds, the ITVF is essentially instant.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience you don't want to use functions on sql server if you can avoid it.

You do want to use tables and SQL Server can optimize joins (esp if they cache.)

There is no reason not to use a parameter table and join to it.

For example make a table Parms with int or string key and valueInt.

In this example I use a string key:

```
SELECT
    TOP 1 Transactions.DateCreated AS TransactionDateTime,
    Transactions.FKPersonID,
    Transactions.FKRequestID
FROM
    Transactions
JOIN Parms AS CTID ON CTID.Key = 'ReturnCollectionTransactionID'
WHERE
    ((Transactions.FKPersonID = @PersonID) AND
    (Transactions.FKRequestID = @RequestID) AND
    (Transactions.FKTransxTypeID = CTID.ValueInt))
ORDER BY
    Transactions.DateTime DESC
```

Note the column name of ValueInt.  In my experience it is useful to have a number of columns in your Params table of different types.  So you would have a ValueInt and a ValueStr column.

You could also have two tables, one for ints and one for strings.

Comment: That's a very interesting approach and one that I think might definitely be worth considering if we do some refactoring at a later date.  I agree about not wanting to use functions but sometimes they are the lesser of two evils (the other side of the equation being that you need to get paid for the work you put in!)

Comment: Inline functions _are_ optimized, that's kind of the point of the name "inline".